# Stacking bootstrap columns (col-md-*)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a system where I display a notification as a bootstrap panel inside a custom col-md-

Here is the function:

```
function showBootstrapNotification(notificationTitle, notificationContent, notificationColor, notificationSize) {
    console.log('trying to execute notification');

    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    var notificationHtml = '';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="col-md-' + notificationSize + ' col-centered" style="margin-top: 6%;">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="draggable panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: ' + notificationColor + '">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    const newNot = $(notificationHtml);
    notificationArea.prepend(newNot);
    newNot.draggable();
}
```

What I want to know is, how can I stack the col-md's on top of each other? I also need to stop them moving them I close a certain col-md and it re-positions the other ones.

I guess what I am looking for is a way of deciding how wide I want my panel, without it specifically re positioning and putting columns underneath each other etc. I simply just want multiple col-md's stacking on top of each other.

What have I tried?

```
.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This stacks them but for some reason, it messed up the height of of the background of panel-body.

Comment: Do you want them to always stack? If so, why not just use `col-md-12` instead? If you just want them to stack at different screen sizes, then you can go up to `col-lg-xx` or down to `col-sm-xx`.

Comment: I feel like you think when I say "stack" you mean like a list, I want them on top of each other do div2 would be covering div1 and div3 would be covering div2 kind of thing.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Stack usually means display as a list when talking about bootstrap columns. `position:absolute` should work.

Comment: As I said in my post, when adding that the height of the panel messes up the centering of it, the col-centered doesn't apply when doing that.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide any more help at the moment, but it might help other responders to know what custom CSS code you have for `col-centered`

Comment: I think you should clarify with a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to stack vertically just remove the `float`..

```
.col-md-1,.col-md-2,.col-md-3,.col-md-4,.col-md-5,.col-md-6,.col-md-7,.col-md-8,.col-md-9,.col-md-10,.col-md-11,.col-md-12 {
    float:none;
}
```

But it's not a good practice to override Bootstrap like this so I'd use a custom class like `float-none` and just add it to the columns..

```
.float-none {
    float:none;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/l1XNBUMRNA